# How to write this string parsing more Ruby-idiomatic?

Tags: ruby

I am parsing simple string inputs, like: "Hello world! :-)" and translate them to an array which splits the words and might do some modifications. I have produced the following code which is working, but it seems not be very Ruby idiomatic. How can I improve it?

```
$mapping = Hash[
  "X" => "CODE_X",
  "Y" => "CODE_Y",
  "Z" => "CODE_Z",
]

def translate(input)
  result = []
  tmp = ""
  input.each_char do |c|
    if $mapping.has_key?(c)
      if result != ""
        result << "normal " + tmp
        tmp = ""
      end
      result << "special " + $mapping[c]
    else
      tmp += c
    end
  end
  if tmp != ""
    result << "normal " + tmp
  end
  return result
end
```

It seems to contain unnecessary many lines making it hard to read. What does it do, maybe an example helps:

```
translate("HelloXworldYZ") =>
["normal Hello", "special CODE_X", "normal world", "special CODE_Y", "special CODE_Z"]
```

Or in English: Parse the String characterwise and concatenate the characters again. Add them to the result array as "normal " + string until (1) there are no more characters or (2) there is a special character (mapping), them add the string to the array AND add the special character as "special " + mapping and continue with the rest of the string.

Comment: Could you describe tranformation logic in plain English?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Okay, tried it. See my edited question.

Comment: It does not look like plain English to me.

Comment: You should look into using [`StringScanner`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html); it is more efficient than going one character at a time, but lets you extract content up until the next matching regex pattern.

Comment: Your plain English description and your test case don't match up. From your plain English description, the result should be `["normal Hello", "special CODE_X", "normal world", "special CODE_Y", "normal", "special CODE_Z"]`.

Comment: This should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. See [the FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) for why.

Comment: Since the question asks for ruby idiomatic, I have to ding you a point for having a global variable. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def translate(input,map)
  input.split(/([#{Regexp.escape map.keys.join}])/).map do |part|
    map.key?(part) ? "special #{map[part]}" : "normal #{part}" unless part.empty?
  end.compact
end

p translate( "HelloXworldYZ", 'X'=>'CODE_X', 'Y'=>'CODE_Y', 'Z'=>'CODE_Z' )
#=> ["normal Hello", "special CODE_X", "normal world", "special CODE_Y", "special CODE_Z"]
```

Comment: And (keeping up with the Jörg's ;) if you want an 'empty' `"normal "` between Y and Z, then just `input.split(/([#{Regexp.escape map.keys.join}])/).map{ |part| map.key?(part) ? "special #{map[part]}" : "normal #{part}" }`

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$mapping = { 'X' => 'CODE_X', 'Y' => 'CODE_Y', 'Z' => 'CODE_Z' }

def translate(input)
  input.
    split(/([#{$mapping.keys.map(&Regexp.method(:escape)).join}])/).
    each_slice(2).
    map {|normal, special| [unless normal.empty? then "normal #{normal}" end, "special #{$mapping[special]}"] }.
    map(&:compact).
    flatten
end

translate("HelloXworldYZ")
# => ["normal Hello", "special CODE_X", "normal world", "special CODE_Y", "special CODE_Z"]
```

Note that your plain English description and your test case don't match up. From your plain English description, the result should be `["normal Hello", "special CODE_X", "normal world", "special CODE_Y", "normal", "special CODE_Z"]`. In that case, it's even simpler:

```
$mapping = { 'X' => 'CODE_X', 'Y' => 'CODE_Y', 'Z' => 'CODE_Z' }

def translate(input)
  input.
    split(/([#{$mapping.keys.map(&Regexp.method(:escape)).join}])/).
    each_slice(2).
    map {|normal, special| [['normal', unless normal.empty? then normal end].compact.join(' '), "special #{$mapping[special]}"] }.
    flatten
end

translate("HelloXworldYZ")
# => ["normal Hello", "special CODE_X", "normal world", "special CODE_Y", "normal", "special CODE_Z"]
```

But the `strscan` library may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mapping = Hash[
  "x" => "CODE_X",
  "y" => "CODE_Y",
  "z" => "CODE_Z",
]

def translate(input)
  $mapping.keys.each { |char| input.gsub!(char, "___#{char}___") } 
  array = input.split(/(___.___)/)
  result = []

  array.each do |word|
    if word.match /___.___/
      result << "special #{$mapping[word[3]]}"
    else
      result << "normal #{word}" unless word.empty?
    end
  end
  result
end

translate("Helloxworldyz")
#=> ["normal Hello", "special CODE_X", "normal world", "special CODE_Y", "special CODE_Z"]
```

Comment: Looks like the whole marking stuff with underscores would not have been necessary. At least I got to post an ascii regex ass ;)